# How to get count of selected rows in excel using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to get count of selected rows listing device IDs ignoring the blank cells using Java. I am using Apache POI to handle excel sheet for selenium automation.

The count should start from 3rd row (ie LV431408) till 17th row (ie A9N26924).

I used sheet.getPhysicalNumberofRows() but it consider the blank cells.

Please refer to screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should use below code for get total row exclude blank.

```
int count = 0;
for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
            if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ||
                cell.getStringCellValue().trim().length() > 0) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to consider blank.

Comment: The answer is  [, , , , A9A26924, A9A26927, A9F77463, A9N18377, A9N18542, A9N21024, A9N21025, A9N21026, A9N26924, A9N26927, A9N26946, A9V11463, LV431408, LV431536, LV434554]

Comment: How to avoid the blank comma ?

Comment: aha, you cell have a space in it, so you should check if value is blank, I updated the answer again

Comment: So i think that cell is not blank, please double check by getStringCellValue() and check itself code point for finding exactly what is its character, so you can exclude it in code.

Comment: using getStringCellValue(), I get blank.

Comment: You should double check those 4 blank cell by this code cell.getStringCellValue().codePointAt(0), if that is space the return must be 32, check and tell me what is its value.

Comment: I used the code int wh=wb.getSheet("Facturation des matériaux").getRow(18).getCell(3).getStringCellValue().codePointAt(0);

and the output is java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Comment: there is 4 cell seem like blank in your column, check all of those cell, perhaps it can help :)

Comment: for random getRow(25), it is showing java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: if it throw that exception it will not pass cell.getStringCellValue().trim().length() > 0, so how can count be increase, this is so strange.

Comment: Yes I tried to modify your code, still error persists.

Comment: you should log all codePointAt(0) of all cell out for checking

Comment: It is showing same error of nullpointerexception in all case.

Comment: Appreciate your effort and time in resolving issue.

Comment: Issue still not resolved. Guess it need to find some other approach.

Comment: i think problem come from you sheet, try a new blank sheet and make some test data for this

Comment: I tried the code on the new blank sheet.
Its display all reference plus blanks.